# In clojure, what is assocEx for?

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am implementing a custom data structure, that, for all intents and purposes, is a sorted map. I wanted to program it so that I can use all of clojure's abstractions when it comes to maps, such as `assoc`, `count`, etc. In order to do that, I need to extend clojure's `clojure.lang.IPersistentMap` protocol to my new sorted map type.

My question is this: What does `assocEx` do, or what is its purpose? Calling it on a normal clojure map shows that it differs from `assoc` in that it throws an exception if you try to insert a key/value pair where the key already exists in the map:

```
user> (.assocEx (cast clojure.lang.IPersistentMap {:a :b}) :a 1)
RuntimeException Key already present  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:219)
```

This is different from `assoc`, which simply replaces the old value in the map with the new one:

```
user> (.assoc (cast clojure.lang.IPersistentMap {:a :b}) :a 1)
{:a 1}
```

But I can't seem to find a "clojure" function (one where the interop form/cast is not used above) that displays this functionality. Where do we see the effects of this function using the normal clojure abstraction functions like `assoc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing ever uses `assocEx` anymore. It is a remnant of an earlier time. If you are writing your own map type, you can implement `(assocEx [m k v] (throw (Exception.)))`.